# Can Spark narrow transformation produce re-shuffle?

Tags: apache-spark

I understand that in Spark `map()` is a narrow transformation hence no shuffle is necessary. But if `map()` can change keys, then it can happen that the data need re-shuffle after map is finished, i.e. it is not anymore a one to one partition. So why is it considered narrow transformation? thanks.

Comment: Although it may mess up the keys, `map()` itself is local operation and does not involve shuffling. You may perform a `map()`, mess up the keys, then perform another `map()`, and another `map()`... None of these requires shuffling data around the partitions, which is why it is considered narrow.

Answer (score 2):

Spark `narrow transformation` does not lead to  the `shuffling` of data .

If we will take an example of this

```
map(func)
filter(func)
flatMap(func)
mapPartitions(func)
mapPartitionsWithIndex(func)
sample(withReplacement, fraction, seed)
union(otherDataset)
intersection(otherDataset)
distinct([numTasks]))
```

Describe the code .

```
scala> val a  = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3)).distinct
scala> a.toDebugString
MappedRDD[5] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
  MapPartitionsRDD[4] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
    **ShuffledRDD[3] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)**
      MapPartitionsRDD[2] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
        MappedRDD[1] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
          ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
```

If you will see here only the Wide transformation caused the Shuffling of data .
But the Narrow transformation will not be the cause of shuffling of data.

Below is a snapshot from [sparksummit](https://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/dev-ops-training)

[This is wide transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mUrG.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks. What I see in yor example is that collect() re-shuffled data but the result is till 1 partition, right? So it is not an actual re-shuffle?

Answer (score 0):

map function in spark is narrow transformation and it definitely **does not cause shuffle**. But if you change keys and have other operations dependent on it, they may cause shuffle.

Example:

Data is partitioned by key1 and you are performing map on your data and changing values in key1 field, this will cause no shuffle.

next operation performed is a group by and again it uses the key1 field, here shuffle will occur and this shuffle can be more or less depending on how you change key1 in your map function above.

If you just consider map function alone, it does not cause any shuffle. But it will impact the rest of the operations following it.